# setInterval calling class method

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, timer

I cannot make the timer to call my class method. This works fine:

```js
MyInput = class {
 constructor(params) {
  let input = params.input;
  input.addEventListener('focus', this.setTimer);
 }

 setTimer() {
  this.timer = window.setInterval(() => {
   console.log('yay');
  }, 300);
 }
};
```

but this:

```js
MyInput = class {
 constructor(params) {
  let input = params.input;
  input.addEventListener('focus', this.setTimer);
 }

 setTimer() {
  this.timer = window.setInterval(this.lookupOptions, 300);
 }

 lookupOptions() {
  console.log('yay');
 }
};
```

doesn't call the `lookupOptions` method but instead, my developer tools in the browser stops debugger every 300ms (checked with different values - always in synch with the timer). After a while, it opens some strange file `VM[number]` with different numbers. I have no idea why it doesn't work. When I used timer outside the class in the same way it worked fine it seems like some problem with calling the class method but I cannot figure out what the problem might be. Could you please help?

Comment: window.setInterval(this.lookupOptions.bind(this), 300);

Comment: @enno.void Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: Use arrow functions to keep the instance as context: `input.addEventListener("focus", e => this.setTimer(e));` and `this.timer = window.setInterval(() => this.lookupOptions(), 300);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `setInterval` calls the function it changes the context of `this` to the scope of the `setInterval`, which would be the `window` object.

Scope the callback in `setInterval` by wrapping it with an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). This prevents the scope from being changed.

```
MyInput = class {
    constructor(params) {
        let input = params.input;
        input.addEventListener("focus", () => {
            this.setTimer();
        });
    }

    setTimer() {
        this.timer = window.setInterval(() => {
            this.lookupOptions();
        }, 300);
    }
  
    lookupOptions() {
         console.log("yay");
    }
}
```

Or use the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method, that is present on each function object to manually set the scope for `this`.

```
MyInput = class {
    constructor(params) {
        let input = params.input;
        const boundSetTimer = this.setTimer.bind(this)
        input.addEventListener("focus", boundSetTimer);
    }

    setTimer() {
        const boundLookupOptions = this.lookupOptions.bind(this)
        this.timer = window.setInterval(boundLookupOptions, 300);
    }
  
    lookupOptions() {
         console.log("yay");
    }
}
```

Or use the experimental [public fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields), which do somewhat the same as arrow function expressions, but as a method of an object.

```
MyInput = class {
    constructor(params) {
        let input = params.input;
        input.addEventListener("focus", this.setTimer);
    }

    setTimer = () => {
        this.timer = window.setInterval(this.lookupOptions, 300);
    }
  
    lookupOptions = () => {
         console.log("yay");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately bind approach gives me "ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.setTimer (clinput.js:44)" error while arrow method "is not a function" error.

Comment: You also need `this.setTimer.bind(this)`

Comment: Why then `input.addEventListener("focus", this.setTimer)` in construction works without binding?

Comment: Because in the constructor, `this` references the instance, so `this.setTimer` correctly points to the method. Without the binding though, `this` *inside* `setTimer` points to the input instead.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you so much for the explanation! Now I understand how it works. And it is working!